# EyeFi cannot find uploadkey

Tags: python, sd-card, photography

I just got an Eye-Fi 2GB share Wi-Fi card and I am trying to get its upload key to make it work with a standalone python server.

This card got EOL'ed so I can't set it up and retrieve its upload key. I've never set it up so it doesn't exist in `Settings.xml`. Eye-Fi Manager will just redirect to `manager.eye.fi` which redirects to the EOL notice.

Is there a way to generate or get the upload key?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.keenai.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000781908-Finding-your-lost-activation-code

I've had to do this a billion times. Also, make sure that the one you recently bought is not one of the older "bricked" cards.

I'm curious to know how you manage to get it working on python server...that sounds cool.

Comment: It's one of the bricked ones.

Comment: damn man. sorry to hear that. i honestly never use mine anyway...it's sort of a clunky technology. just waiting to upgrade to a wifi enabled camera.